# Sharetribe: Change "Minimal Order (quantity)" to "Minimal Order"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sharetribe

In `views app/views/listings/show.haml`, I have this code:

```
- if @listing.price
  .row
    .col-12
      .listing-price
        %span.listing-price-amount
          = humanized_money_with_symbol(@listing.price).upcase
        - with_quantity_text(@current_community, @listing) do |text|
          %span.listing-price-quantity
            = text
```

On the product show page, it displays the text:

> Minimal Order (quantity)

How can I change this text to just "Minimal Order"?

Comment: How does your `with_quantity_text` helper method look like? Does your app use `I18n`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much you've customised Sharetribe, you should find this string in `/config/locales/en.yml` under the key `listings.show.price.per_quantity_unit`.

`with_quantity_text` ends up [here](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe/blob/master/app/helpers/listings_helper.rb#L119), and uses I18n to grab the string. YMMV if you've customised any of the helpers here though.